# Enabling two apps to use a single sound device

Tags: asterisk, alsa

I have:

- USB Sound which is alsa "Device" or "hw:1,0"
- Asterisk console configured to use "plughw:1,0"

This works, letting me use the USB Sound for making and receiving voice calls via Asterisk.

I also want to use multimon to decode DTMF tones during the call. If I stop Asterisk I can run "aoss multimon -T DTMF" to decode the tones successfully but in order to do so I had to create an /etc/asoundrc file like so:

```
pcm.dsp0 { type plug slave.pcm "hw:1,0" }
```

Starting Asterisk, which grabs the "plughw:1,0" means I get an error trying to run multimon. I believe this is because only one app can access an alsa device at any one time.

I think I need to split the hw:1,0 into two new alsa devices, which I have been trying to do using alsa plugins (dmix/multi) but I'm afraid I can't get my head around how to get these configured!

p.s. I want to use multimon as I also have other use cases for using it on the same setup to decode other tones than just DTMF.

Comment: This can be done with the `dmix` plugin, which is used automatically by the `default` devide as long as you do not redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

As @CL have pointed, you could use dsnoop for analysing the audio trhough multimon. The following extract has been taken from [Basic Virtual PCM Devices for Playback/Capture, *ALSA* | nairobi-embedded](http://nairobi-embedded.org/alsa_pcm_plugins_capture.html)

> **The dmix[:$CARD...] and dsnoop[:$CARD...] Virtual PCM Devices**
>   A limitation with the hw[:$CARD...] and plughw[$CARD...] virtual PCM devices (on systems with no hardware mixing) is that only one application at a time can access an audio stream. The dmix[:$CARD...] (playback) and dsnoop[:$CARD...] (capture) virtual PCM devices allow mixing or sharing, respectively, of a single stream among several applications without the intervention of a sound server, i.e. these devices use native ALSA library based mechanisms.